# Open Citrix receiver launcher difficulties

Tags: selenium, citrix

I am investigating automating a Citrix test using Selenium, Chrome and Java.  I click on the "Open Citrix" link and get the following window (note when we start up selenium it starts up a fresh Chrome without any of the bookmarks, cookies, etc, so this will have to be done each time even if I click the "Always open these types... box":

[image]

I thought this box might be an alert, so I did (from a method I found) a wait for alert (about 10 seconds) but an alert was never found.  So then I tried counting the number of window handles before and after clicking "Open Citrix" (after waiting 5 or so seconds).  But it was 1 before and after so it is not a new window.  I could not right click on this and select "inspect".  I also searched for "Always open" in the inspect pane (which I had opened from the main window, not the notice).

Any thoughts on how to click "Open Citrix Receiver Launcher" (I don't need to click the Always box).  And yes, Citrix is installed because if I click "Open Citrix" (manually) it takes me right to the login screen.

Comment: One option would be to get a clean browser profile, load that page, click the "Always open these..." check box, and then save that profile. Load that profile when starting up your script and you should be good.

Comment: I don't think they will let me do that?  I will ask. But there is at startup a way to specify options to the Chrome Driver.  Is there any way to put that option at startup?  Or maybe I could add a cookie?

Comment: Not sure if there is a chromedriver option for that... that's why I didn't post an answer. It's just a possible option. I don't know how Citrix stores that setting. A cookie may be an option but you would have to investigate.

Comment: I looked at the settings after running it.  There are several cookies under /Citrix/CL1storeWeb.  Trying to set those cookies I just get an http response that it can't do it.  i tried changing to c:\temp but same problem.  I am not sure how the set cookies works

Comment: OK I see before you can add a cookie you have to be on a web page.  So I go there, click, add the cookies, go back to the old site and click again.  However, unfortunately the app you open from that page does not seem to be able to be accessed via Selenium

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure. From the screenshot you posted, it looks like Citrix Receiver needs to be installed for it to work. I don't know what all is involved in that but I would guess that your best bet would be to install that and set the setting above in a clean profile and then use that for all your scripts. Otherwise it looks like you will have to install the app at the start of each script... which doesn't sound like a good idea (slow, maybe error prone, etc.)

Comment: hi @Tony, were you able to figure out this Citrix pop-up issue with Selenium? It pops up even if the launder is installed. I tried treating it as an alert/modal, and some jquery as well. Nothing works.